# Java program can't execute file it writes to /tmp, no such file or directory

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I am running into trouble with a java program, which attempts to write files to the `/tmp` directory on Ubuntu 18.10. It runs into errors as it can not write the temporary file it expects. It fails for error 2: No such file or directory. The privileges on `/tmp` are default.

I have read this is not a problem with Windows or Mac OS for the reason that it would not be restricted in this way.

How do I solve this? Should I configure my system differently (preferred) or alter the code?

Edit:

The file in question is actually created, permissions are 
`-rwxrwxr-x  1 lucas lucas 51263 Apr 26 11:12 monalisa13902330713449850714bin*`

However, the the program cannot find it:

`monalisa.tools.tinv.TInvariantCalculator$InvokeProcessException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/monalisa13902330713449850714bin" (in directory "/tmp"): error=2, No such file or directory`

The `/tmp` directory is determined correctly by `File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));`

The file is created here:

```java
    toolFile = FileUtils.extractResource("tinv_unix", "monalisa", "bin");
```

```java
    public static File extractResource(URL resource, String prefix,
            String suffix) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.debug("Extracting resource '" + resource.toString() + "'");
        File file = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix);
        file.setExecutable(true, false);
```

Running `exec /tmp/[file name]` returns the same error.

Edit: result of ´strace -e stat,execve -f bash -c /tmp/monalisa1846113800189529428bin´

`

```
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "/tmp/monalisa1846113800189529428"...], 0x7ffdb3fa2b68 /* 59 vars */) = 0
stat("/home/lucas", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/lucas", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/tmp/bin/bash", 0x7ffdd5b7b7d0)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/sbin/bash", 0x7ffdd5b7b7d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/bash", 0x7ffdd5b7b7d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/sbin/bash", 0x7ffdd5b7b7d0)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/bash", 0x7ffdd5b7b7d0)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/sbin/bash", 0x7ffdd5b7b7d0)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1121696, ...}) = 0
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1121696, ...}) = 0
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1121696, ...}) = 0
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1121696, ...}) = 0
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1121696, ...}) = 0
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1121696, ...}) = 0
execve("/tmp/monalisa1846113800189529428bin", ["/tmp/monalisa1846113800189529428"...], 0x55d86a4d0960 /* 59 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/tmp/monalisa1846113800189529428bin", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0744, st_size=51263, ...}) = 0
stat("/tmp/monalisa1846113800189529428bin", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0744, st_size=51263, ...}) = 0
stat("/tmp/monalisa1846113800189529428bin", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0744, st_size=51263, ...}) = 0
stat("/tmp/monalisa1846113800189529428bin", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0744, st_size=51263, ...}) = 0
bash: /tmp/monalisa1846113800189529428bin: No such file or directory
+++ exited with 127 +++`
```

Comment: Does the file still exist when you try to execute it?

Comment: Note that when asking about exceptions you should always post the entire stacktrace and ideally mark the lines of your codes that are mentioned there.

Comment: Could you please paste the result of ```strace -e stat,execve -f bash -c $filename```?

Comment: @LutzHorn I can't execute it, it returns the same error.

Answer (score 3):

I would bet that your /tmp directory is mounted as noexec - which means you're not able to execute any program there.

Possible solutions: write to somewhere else (user's home directory perhaps?) or remove noexec from /etc/fstab for /tmp and remount - but be sure you understand what that implies before you do so.

Comment: I'd say "write somewhere else" is the best option in this case, as you can't know whether users will be able to change their fstab, and it would be bad for them to do that just to run one single program.

Comment: This is not consistent with the error message. /tmp mounted with noexec would result with EPERM, not ENOENT.

Comment: /tmp is not in /etc/fstab

Answer (score 0):

a solution to run a java program with no execution right in /tmp is to redirect java to another folder with the option `-Djava.io.tmpdir=[PATH_TO_FOLDER_YOU_CAN_EXECUTE]`